# STS/Eclipse Loading Wrong Spring Beans XSD

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, xsd, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Spring Tool Suite (3.1.0)/Eclipse is loading the wrong version of a Spring Beans XSD, causing XML validation errors. I've got `spring-beans` 3.2.2.RELEASE on the classpath as a Maven dependency, and so the `profile` attribute of the `<beans>` element should be permissable. Sadly, this flags as an error.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<beans profile="!cloud">
[...]
```

The following is in my XML Catalog settings, and suggest something is setting resolution to version 3.1.4 of Spring Beans. I'm not really sure how I can override this with a dependency from Maven (that could change at any time).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the Spring jar you will probably see that the 3.1.4 xsd is also included in that jar. In this case I would suggest adding the version number to the spring-beans.xsd in the schemaLocation. I monkeyed around with this in an XML editor that could do validation, and found that it helped.

With out the version number the XML editor was pulling in the spring-beans.xsd and the spring-beans-3.2.xsd, and ended up failing validation.

Comment: Thanks, but the tech lead on this project sadly won't allow numbers in the `schemaLocation`.

Comment: I can understand that. I usually leave them out unless I'm trying to trouble shoot one of these odd situations. Let me guess, it only happens on your machine? Then I would look into the Eclipse settings. Does it work when you run Maven on the command line? Look at the Maven version and project POM. If it is any consolation, I hate these types of problems.